# Is it possible to manipulate flask log strings?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have a python flask server that outputs request information.  I'm setting the output file name, level, and format using `logging.basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=log_filename, level=level,
    format='%(asctime)s %(processName)s[%(process)d]: %(levelname)5s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%b %d %H: %M: %S')
```

I want to change the output from something like:

`Dec 10 11:13:27 MainProcess[11111]: INFO: 200 GET /ws?token=supersecretkey`

To something like:

`Dec 10 11:13:27 MainProcess[11111]: INFO: 200 GET /ws?token={hidden}`

I suppose I'm looking for some way to grab the log output string and change it.  Would a filter be the best idea here?

Comment: You have two options to do this that I know of. Filters or Adapters, both of them can add or change contextual information of your log. Check these examples for understanding: (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output)